# When inside for-each loop in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I've an xml which has same elements in 2 different levels I need to compare the value of elements in 2 levels and return matching element's value. For example I've a following xml

```
<root>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
     <Name>xxx</Name>
     <Gender>Male</Gender>
    </profile>
    <profile>
     <Name>yyy</Name>
     <Gender>Female</Gender>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <subroot>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
       <sName>xxx</sName>
       <sAge>10</sAge>
      </profile>
      <profile>
       <sName>yyy</sName>
       <sAge>20</sAge>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  </subroot>
</root>
```

I need to put loop for `//root/subroot/profiles/profile` and get the value of `Name,Age,Gender` elements. Whereas we have to take the Gender element's value by comparing name element value with xpath `//root/profiles/profile`. When I use below code

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//root/subroot/profiles/profile">
    <xsl-for-each select="//root/profiles/profile">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when name=sname>
        <xsl:value-of select="Gender">
       </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:for-each>
  </xsl-for-each>
```

I'm getting corresponding gender value for 1st element when the loop traverse for 2nd element the same value of 1st element is return that is for both xxx,yyy the Gender is return as 'Male'. Someone check this code and let me know any fix for this issue

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to lookup the data from the corresponding profile - say:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="subprofile" match="profile" use="sName" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="profiles/profile">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('subprofile', Name)/sAge"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you prefer the other direction:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="profile" match="profile" use="Name" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="subroot/profiles/profile">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('profile', sName)/*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="sAge"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both cases the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <profile>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <sAge>10</sAge>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <sAge>20</sAge>
  </profile>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any other way using for-each loop. for example if i need to get only <Name> and <Gender> elements in the output

Comment: Im getting below output when i try the same code                                                         <root>
  <profile>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <sAge>10</sAge>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <sAge>Female</sAge>
  </profile>
</root>

Comment: Please edit your question and show the **exact** output you want to get in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

Many join queries are best tackled using a key as explained by @michael.hor257k, but the more general approach is to bind variables:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//root/subroot/profiles/profile">
  <xsl:variable name="outer-profile" select="."/>
  <xsl-for-each select="//root/profiles/profile">
     <xsl:variable name="inner-profile" select="."/>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$outer-profile/x/y/z = $inner-profile/p/q/r">
        ...
       </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:for-each>
  </xsl-for-each>
```